# Static class vs instanced class

Tags: c#, static, state, instance

### Duplicate

> [Should C# methods that *can* be static be static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731763/should-c-methods-that-can-be-static-be-static/731779#731779)

---

Please forgive me if this question seems elementary - I'm looking over some source code that otherwise looks pretty good, but it's raised some questions...

If a given class has no member data - i.e. it doesn't maintain any sort of state, are there any benefits in not marking that class as a static class with static methods?

Are there any benefits in not marking methods which don't maintain state as static?

Thanks!

EDIT: Since someone brought it up, the code I'm looking at is written in c#.

Comment: I would think this depends on what language you're using.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731763/should-c-methods-that-can-be-static-be-static/731779#731779

Comment: I disagree with being duplicate. That one is about methods and this one is about classes. Different issues apply.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Take a closer look. This one is effectively about methods too. The recommendations that apply are the same for both questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. I can think of some reasons:

1. Ease of mocking and unit testing
2. Ease of adding state
3. You could pass it around (as an `interface` or something)

Comment: 4. Overriding implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is a benefit to making them static methods of the class, and on top of that making the class abstract. That way, it's clear to the programmer that this class was never intended to be instantiated and the methods are still available.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a benefit in leaving methods that don't change state non-static, if you intend (or think you might intend) to inherit from the class and override those methods with code that *does* change state.  Though in that case it really should be an abstract class.

Comment: There is obviously no case for making the class abstract if you will need to instantiate the object.

Comment: You still need to use instance types/methods to inherit even if the derived type has no intent on maintaining state since you cannot inherit from static classes or override static methods.

Comment: Agreed.  Though philosophically, at least, there's no reason to instantiate an object that holds no state.

Answer (score 2):

If a class doesn't maintain any state, doesn't have any instance methods, and could be implemented entirely with class methods, I usually take a long hard look at whether its behaviors would in fact make more sense somewhere else. I find they usually seem to have a lot of methods along the lines of `doSomethingWithItem(Item item)`, which would make more sense as an instance method in `Item`.

Yeah, I know this doesn't answer your question, but I think others have covered that pretty well already, and I wanted to get another perspective out there.