# Static Method in Instances

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

Straight up question: If I run code analysis, it tells me to make methods static even in nonstatic classes.
As far as I know, static methods are JITed and run on the Type-Object in the Heap. So wouldn't make a method static in a non static class mean, that the instance has to search the type object in the Heap and run the method there?

Wouldn't that mean a performance issue? Sure it would not be that big of a deal, but I'd still be interested on this.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874363/what-is-better-static-methods-or-instance-methods

Comment: This is performance issue. Non-static method has hidden parameter - reference to the class instance. If reference is not used, it is better to make this method static, excluding additional method parameter.

Comment: Also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135020/advantages-to-using-private-static-methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12279898/113683 gives a thorough explanation

Comment: If you are considering use static methods, remember, static implies thread safety!!!   A static method can be called from any thread at any time and it's up to the static method to make sure it's properly handling concurrency.  For that reason, I generally avoid static methods that aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: @PhilipPittle Common sense: If code analysis tells him to make a method static, it is because it never references anything in the object - that is how the rule is implemented. Which means by definition it can not change the object.

Comment: @TomTom - There are additional race conditions that can occur that have nothing to do with the host object.  If the static method calls a data service (ie database) in a non thread-safe way, this can cause race conditions.

Comment: And how would they call the database in a non thread safe way? WIthout the same applying to instance methods (like using a non thread save static db connection class)? Remember: The analysis proposes the methods to be made static because THEY HAVE NO STATE IN THE OBJECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that.

A static method is actually (imperceptibly) more efficient than a non-static one because (a) it does not have a hidden "this" pointer passed to it and (b) because it's static, the framework doesn't have to do anything about it being virtual (although that last point also applies to non-virtual member methods too, of course).

[Here is an in-depth article about CLR runtime type handling.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) In particular, look at the information there about the MethodTable and the Method Slot Table.

[Here's another good article from Joe Duffy.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/il/article.php/c11849/CLR-Method-Internals-NET-20.htm) It doesn't explicitly talk about static methods, but it does explain how method calls are made at the lowest (assembler) level, so you would be able to see why a static method call is efficient.

Comment: Ok this seems right, but it has to search for the type object to execute it, right?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller It only does that during the JIT process, i.e. once only in the lifetime of the program. For full details, have a look at [this sample chapter from Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" book](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=5A051E94BDA12163&resid=5A051E94BDA12163!1016&app=WordPdf) (Search for "when calling a static method")

Answer (score 1):

Good post about performance comparsion of  static methods vs instance methods: [Performance of static methods vs instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279438/performance-of-static-methods-vs-instance-methods)

TLDR:

- Mostly the performance costs of instance vs static are below
  negligible.
- What costs there are will generally come where you abuse
  static for instance or vice-versa. If you don't make it part of your
  decision between static and instance, you are more likely to get the
  correct result.
- There are rare cases where static generic methods in another type
  result in fewer types being created, than instance generic methods,
  that can make it sometimes have a small benefit to turn rarely used
  (and "rarely" refers to which types it's used with in the lifetime of
  the application, not how often it's called). Once you get what he's
  talking about in that article you'll see that it's 100% irrelevant to
  most static-vs-instance decisions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that you're not calling a static method upon an instance, but on the class itself. Any method that does not directly rely on instance information could (and based upon code analysis also should) be marked static and then be called like this:

```
NonstaticClass.TheStaticMethod();
```

instead if this

```
NonstaticClass inst = new NonstaticClass();
inst.TheStaticMethod();
```

This is because less overhead is required to look up and run a static method than a non-static method on a class instance.

Comment: My question was more about why it is less overheard instead of more since it has to search the type in the Heap

Comment: Ah, I see. As others have answered, the point is not having to care for `this` pointer and the VMT.