# Static Methods : When and when not

Tags: .net, tdd, domain-driven-design

I am new to TDD and DDD and I have one simple question regarding static methods in general. Most of the gurus of TDD says in one word that static methods are bad (and that we should forget about creating tons of static utilities that we (um or I) used to make before as they are not testable. I can see why they are not testable ( a great clarification article can be found [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html) for those who are interested but I guess I am the only noob here :( ) but I was wondering is there a nice and clean guideline for using statics from TDD point of view?

This may be really silly question for most of you but some tips would be great and I just want to know how experts here think of static stuff. Thanks in advance.

Edit: While looking for answer I found 2 other nice threads regarding usage of static ( not TDD concern though) which I guess are good reads for those who are interested(myself inclusive).

- [Topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731763/should-c-methods-that-can-be-static-be-static)
- [Topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/c-method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may have slightly misunderstood.

Static methods are testable. Take this method as an example:

```
public static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

You can test this by testing that the return value is what you expect based on the arguments passed in.

Where static methods become troublesome when testing is when you need to introduce a mock.

Let's say I have some code that calls the `File.Delete()` static method. To test my code without relying on the file system, I would want to replace/mock this call with a test version that just verifies that it has been called from the code being tested. This is easy to do if I had an instance of an object on which `Delete()` was being called. Most (all?) mocking frameworks can not mock static methods, so using a static method in my code forces me to test it differently (usually by calling the real static method).

To test something like this, I would introduce an interface:

```
interface IFileDeleter
{
    void Delete(string file);
}
```

My code would then take an instance of an object that implements this interface (either in the method call or as a parameter in the constructor), and then call its `Delete()` method to do the delete:

```
void MyMethod(string file)
{
    // do whatever...
    deleter.Delete(file);
}
```

To test this, I can make a mock of the `IFileDeleter` interface and simply verify that its `Delete()` method had been called. This removes the need to have a real file system as part of the test.

This may look like the code is more complex (which it is), but it pays for itself in making it far easier to test.

Comment: +1! Typemock can mock static methods, but it's better to avoid them (when they will need to be mocked).

Comment: +1 Thanks heaps for a comprehensive answer. I will just wait for few more answers (if any) before selecting an answer for the sake of sharing knowledge

Comment: Hm what I asked was indeed a bit silly now that I read your answer. yeah you are right I kinda missed the point when I asked the question. It's mocking when they real trouble arises; not testing the method itself specially when it's just a utility method.

Answer (score 8):

In general, if the method:

- Is slow
- Is long
- Contains complex logic
- Uses the file system
- Connects to a database
- Calls a web service

then avoid making it static. (See @adrianbanks' answer for an excellent discussion of the reasons behind this and the alternatives.)

Basically, only make it static if it's a short in-memory convenience method (like many extension methods).

Comment: I like your answer a lot. It makes sense, you take the hit of testing the logic of the static as part of the SUT, for the convenience that the Static utility brings you, if and only if it does not have any of the traits you spelled out. So given a fast, simple, side-effect free, static method, you assume it to be a primitive, an extension of your language, and just use it in your units without isolation.

Answer (score 8):

Avoiding statics is certainly the way to go, but when you can't or you're working with Legacy code, the following option is available.  Following on from adrianbanks answer above, let's say you have the following code (apologies, its in Java as I don't know C#):

```
public void someMethod() {
   //do somethings
   File.delete();
   //do some more things
}
```

you can refactor the File.delete() into its own method like this:

```
public void someMethod() {
   //do somethings
   deleteFile();
   //do some more things
}

//protected allows you to override in a subclass
protected void deleteFile() { 
   File.delete();
}
```

and then in preparation for your unit test create a mock class which extends the original one and stubs out that functionality:

```
//Keep all the original functionality, but stub out the file delete functionality to 
//prevent it from using the real thing and while you're at it, keep a record that the
//method was called.
public class MockClass extends TheRealClass {
    boolean fileDeleteCalled = false;

    @Override
    protected void deleteFile()
        //don't actually delete the file, 
        //just record that the method to do so was called
        fileDeleteCalled = true;
    }

    public boolean fileDeleteCalled() { 
        return fileDeleteCalled; 
    }
}
```

and finally in your unit test:

```
//This would normally be instantiated in the @Before method
private MockClass unitUnderTest = new MockClass();

@Test
public void testFileGetsDeleted(){
    assertFalse(unitUnderTest.fileDeleteCalled());
    unitUnderTest.someMethod();
    assertTrue(unitUnderTest.fileDeleteCalled());
}
```

Now you've executed all the functionality of someMethod() without actually deleting the file, and you still have the ability to see if that method was called.

Comment: someone give him more upvotes please for the nice example and clarification