# Why the default constructor of class Program is Never executed?

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace TestApp
{
  class Program
  {
    public Program()
    {
      var breakpoint1 = 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] arguments)
    {
      var breakpoint2 = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

1. Why *`breakpoint 1`* is never hit , but it hits *`breakpoint 2`* always?
2. And is there a way to execute the default constructor before entering `Main()` ?

Comment: You should read about the difference of static and non-static methods.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Main` method is executed without an instance of the `Program` class, which is possible because it is a static method. Static methods are methods that can be called without the need to construct/instantiate an object from the class. They can be called directly on the Class itself like this:

```
Program.Main(new string[0]); 

// executes the Main static method on Program class 
// with empty string array as argument
```

The constructor is not a static method, to hit that breakpoint you need to instantiate the `Program` class, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] arguments)
{
  var breakpoint2 = 0;
  new Program(); // breakpoint1 will be hit
}
```

Alternatively you can [make the constructor static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), though admittedly it is not [really that useful from a testability standpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3973109/3713) and also implies that you're going to have static variables (that are globally available):

```
static Program() {
    var breakpoint1 = 0; 
    // breakpoint will be hit without an instance of the Program class
}
```

You can read more about [static methods here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method).

Answer (score 20):

You are not instantiating the class. You are running a `static Main()` method. The run time will load the class and invoke the `Main()` method .It doesn't need an instance of the class to invoke the `Main()` method. Constructor will run when you construct(instantiate) an object.

Answer (score 9):

Your method is static: it will run without an instance of the class existing.  Your constructor is not: it is only executed when you create an instance of the class (that is, when you write `new Program()`).

In order to hit your breakpoint, most likely you want to change your constructor to be 
`static Program()` instead.

Comment: Access modifiers aren't allowed on static constructors, i.e. it would be simply `static Program(){}`, not `public static Program(){}`

Comment: +1 for mention of static constructors, though there's no need for public since it's called implicitly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the correction - copying and pasting without due attention!

Answer (score 4):

The entry point to your program is equivalent to calling `TestApp.Program.Main(args)`. The `Program` class doesn't get instantiated.