# Using private static methods Instead of private methods In C#

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style, static, static-methods

When its recommended to use a private static method instead of a private [instance] method?

***EDIT:*** 
i am looking for a good (or best practice) about that .i am wondering Is this technic used by microsoft or not?does anybody know something about that ? i coudnt find any blog ,article or sample source code that explains this topic.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Other similar questions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/c-method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it/169423#169423) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731763/should-c-methods-that-can-be-static-be-static)

Answer (score 3):

`Static` word in the beginning of the method declaration, basically is a sign of stateless, so what is happening inside is a pure action, or at least should be.

If you want to use `private static`: use it like API functions of your class that just make some calculations/reports... and not change the actual *state* of the object, which basically is done by `instance` methods.

This is an *expected* way of implementing, which doens't mean that is *mandatory*, but as it's *expected*,  it will help other developers understand your code, and help understand code to you after a couple of years, when you will come back to your project and already have forgot everything.

Regards.

Comment: `static` methods often have side effects, on static variables or method arguments.  It's no sign of "statelessness" whatsoever.

Comment: @Ben: infact, I wrote that this is expected behaviour, but not mandatory. You always can pass to a static method instance of class which changed inside of that method. Matter of design choice. But in general, at least me, when looking on static method, I immagine that it SHOULD be something that doesn't affect state.