# How can I configure Eclipse/FindBugs to warn for methods that does not use any instance variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

Not using any instance variables indicates that they should be static methods. Is there a way to configure Eclipse or FindBugs to show warnings for this kind of methods?

Comment: If that was expanded to include not using any instance methods I could see the premise being true. I started my custom detectors using [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-findbug2/); man that seems like a long time ago now.

Comment: They should also be private or final, because else a subclass might want to override the method and use instance methods/variables.

Comment: If in Eclipse Window->Tools->Java Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Code Style-> **Method can be static** and **Method can potentially be static** is what you're looking for, I'd turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [findbugs bug descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) I couldn't find any detector that matches your specific use case. So you would either have to use a different tool that supports this analysis or write your own.

A [quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=write%20findbugs%20detector&t=canonical) brings up many different tutorials on how to write a custom detector.

As to whether it's a good idea to make every method static if possible, you could also refer to [this great stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731925/1396068).