# Good reasons for static methods?

Tags: c#, static, resharper, static-methods

I use static methods for things I really MEANT to be static. I use ReSharper for better code quality. Sometimes ReSharper suggests that a method can be made static.

When I got the following class:

```
public class WhatEverClass {
    private string DoSomethingFancy(string input) 
    {
       string fancyStuff;
       // Fancy Stuff here
       return fancyStuff;
    }

    public WhatEverClass() {
       string awesome=DoSomethingFancy("some fancy string");
    }
}
```

ReSharper might say "DoSomethingFancy can be made static".

I know it *could* be made static, but is there a good reason to really do this? Or should I just ignore these suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReSharper complains when method can be static, but isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790281/resharper-complains-when-method-can-be-static-but-isnt)

Comment: I think you should not mark it as static unless you are 100% certain the method will not require state at some point.

Comment: another similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021054/why-does-resharper-suggest-const-static-operations

Comment: @astander I don't think its a duplicate. The linked article is a very general question. Mine has a specific example and the wish why this one should be made static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By defining a method static, so a procedure that *computes* something, you *manifest an intent* to a consumer of your `API` about *statelessness of your function*.

When we use `static` function, we *do not expect* it saves a state of computation or some computed internal value somewhere in it's internal `static private` variables, so the next call to that function may have different result even with the same parameters passed during the first call.

In short: whenever you see a function that just executes an action over parameter and not preserve some state, it is a good candidate for making it `static`.

Comment: +1 for actually providing some useful reasoning behind this, and not just a variant of "use static if you don't explicitly need something else...".

Answer (score 1):

If your method doesn't need to say or change the state of an instanciated object, then it should be static.

Comment: TypeMock have the capability of doing test to static methods. But yes, static methods are a huge problem with unit testing.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but private static methods should not (negativly) effect unit tests at all?

Comment: If the static method doesn't change states of other classes it would not be any problem with the unit test. If the method is called from another classes it is not a unit test, it's more like integrtion testing.

Answer (score 1):

The usual notion is , if you are not creating an instance of anything, you could declare it static. As to where it should be used, ReSharper gives you suggestions based on standard programming practices. However, i take 'standard programming practices' with a grain of salt. Its a matter of personal programming preference for some. Here is a detailed reference on the topic :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because you will invoke the `WhatEverClass()` method from outside the class by creating `WhatEverClass` instance. So the value for every instance will be different, because the variable is local, and will be created every time you create an instance of the class.

But if you want to keep the same value for all instances, then you can make it `static` so it will be created once in a memory and all instances will use it.

Comment: Sorry. But it is not about static values here.

Answer (score 0):

Beware the consequences of making a method static!

By making your method static, you make it that much harder for consumers to stub out your implementation of the algorithm and replace it with one of their own (obviously if the method is `private` you have no such worries).

Consumers of your static method have your implementation baked in to their code - they cannot use dependency injection to resolve a specific instance of your algorithm (without a bit of work). This makes their system that much harder to test, and in general lends itself to a less extensible code base.

Comment: I do not want do provide a framework or something like that. It is a project for a customer where I and team members have the source but no one "outside" will use it as a source for something else

Comment: You always have consumers - whether you consider them to be external or not.  The primary application, as well as the test harness are two consumers with different requirements. What if your test harness wants to test an aspect of your system without using the specific implementation of your algorithm?  The other members of your team will be consuming your code - yes?

Answer (score -1):

If the method `DoSomethingFancy` does not use anything in the object `WhatEverClass` then it should, in my book, be made static since it does not in fact have anything to do with the object in which it is used.

Comment: The problem is that you can not test methods that use your static function ever. You can't mock the static function, which is a big problem.