# C# Nested Classes and Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, encapsulation, nested-class, access-modifiers

Just need some help with nested classes and inheritance..

```
namespace blah
{
    private abstract class InheritedSomething
    {
        public void doSomething() {};
    }

    class OtherClass : InheritedSomething
    {
        //Stuff

        class NestedClass : InheritedSomething
        {
            //Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing things? It seems a bit redundant that `NestedClass` inherits `InerhitedSomething` when its parent class already inherits this... But when I remove the inheritance from `NestedClass` it asks me to make `doSomething()` a static method.

So my question is, which way is "correct" - Both `OtherClass` and `NestedClass` inheriting `InheritedSomething` or only `OtherClass` inherits `InheritedSomething` and `doSomething()` becomes `public static void`?

Thanks!

Comment: Should doSomething have the same implementation in both classes?  Or does doSomething differ in OtherClass vs NestedClass?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this design.

The suggestion that a method can be made static is a completelly separate issue. Note, that **can** doesn't mean it **should**. (Read more about deciding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790281/resharper-complains-when-method-can-be-static-but-isnt)). When you remove the inheritance, `doSomething` isn't overriding anymore which makes it eligible to be checked for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Correct or not depends on what you intend to do.

Inner types have privileged access to enclosing type members but do not derive from it.

What is your intention with these classes?