# is var x = new Stuff(); x.DoStuff(); faster than new Stuff().DoStuff();?

Tags: c#, optimization

is `var x = new Stuff(); x.DoStuff();`faster than `new Stuff().DoStuff();` ?

I'm not sure why but I noticed in my code that the first method makes it faster, anybody knows which one is faster and why ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's doing the same thing in the compiler anyway. Have you compared the IL for both?

Comment: How did you measure it? I think it is quite hard to measure such a small piece of code. You'd better optimize the DoStuff method, and only if it is a really bottleneck.

Comment: From such a terse code example, with no indication of how things are declared, I fail to see how any reasonable benchmarks could be designed. By the way I didn't down-vote this. Please consider making the question a little more elaborated, and the code sample more explicit.

Comment: +1: Although it's true that you should not do this kind of micro-optimization in your code, your question (and the answers) are interesting from a theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the second should be faster as it performs fewer operations. Let's take this program for example:

```
class Program
{
    public void Foo() { }

    static void Main() 
    {}

    static void Method1()
    {
        var x = new Program();
        x.Foo();
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        new Program().Foo();
    }
}
```

Here's how Method1 and Method2 look like when compiled in Release mode:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Method1() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class Program x)
    L_0000: newobj instance void Program::.ctor()
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: ldloc.0 
    L_0007: callvirt instance void Program::Foo()
    L_000c: ret 
}

.method private hidebysig static void Method2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: newobj instance void Program::.ctor()
    L_0005: call instance void Program::Foo()
    L_000a: ret 
}
```

Of course this sort of micro-optimization questions should never be asked.

Comment: Furthermore, the JIT compiler will probably create the same machine code out of that IL anyway.

Comment: +1 for you: "Of course this sort of micro-optimization questions should never be asked." -1 for the question.

Comment: Is that with all optimisations enables? I've seen the compiler remove variables on occasion, making them identical...

Answer (score 7):

It seems that in this case you can make *DoStuff* a static method.

So rather then use

```
Stuff.DoStuff();
```

Have a look at

- [Static Classes and Static Class
  Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx)
- [C# method can be made static, but
  should it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/c-method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it)

Answer (score 4):

This is the IL code that they produce:

`new Stuff().DoStuff();`:

```
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.Stuff::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication1.Stuff::DoStuff()
  IL_000a:  ret
```

`var x = new Stuff(); x.DoStuff();`:

```
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleApplication1.Stuff x)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.Stuff::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication1.Stuff::DoStuff()
  IL_000c:  ret
```

When iterating over the two variations 1000000 times, the `new Stuff().DoStuff();` version uses around 20% less time. Nothing I would bother about (the difference was 0.8 ms on one million iterations).

Comment: Yeah I think if that miniscule amount of difference mattered to me, i wouldn't be using .NET in the first place

Answer (score 3):

IMO the speed should be exactly the same for both versions. Maybe your benchmark is flawed?

Answer (score 1):

The first version needs to store the reference to x in the locals, which the latter version doesn't, this cannot be done without consuming additional instructions. However, even the slightest change in the code will change the performance.

And please do not over-estimate the efficiency of the JIT'er, the JIT needs to balance speed of compilation with the efficiency of the code generated, the JIT'er is not the pen-ultimate application for generating machine code from CIL code.