# Clarification needed for prototype/object statement and chain traversal

Tags: javascript

While still struggling to read "You don't know JS", I am start to have good idea(love this series). I think I get the hang of prototype but I ran into below code.

```
   var myObject = {
     a:2
   };

   Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myObject, "a");
```

And while I fully comprehend the output and its meaning, I was trying to use my understanding (or lack thereof) of prototype and wanted to do below.

```
   myObject.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
```

I thought it would traverse up the **proto** chain up to Object's prototype and get that method but as it turns out, Object's prototype does not have this (assume this is not part of prototype of object as I am looking up the doc, at least I don't see it as part of prototype and it says it's a method). So instead of being Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, I assume this is just Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor.

Am I understanding this correctly and what is the reason why Object's method is not on all prototype?

Comment: We won't be able to tell you why a design decision was made, unless one of us was on the committee which designed the language. We can only speculate, which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. But, as the existing answers show, we can tell you that you are understanding correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is not part of the prototype of Object... it's a method

You're exactly right. This can be immediately verified in a js console:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
getOwnPropertyDescriptor() { [native code] }
> Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
undefined
```

In a more strictly OOP language, you might call `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` a static method. More properly, it's not part of the prototype chain.

Comment: Is this just design issue? Why didn't javascript people put everything under prototype when they were designing Object in the first place??

Comment: "Why didn't javascript people do X?" is a complicated question, mostly to do with the fact the Brendan Eich built javascript in a few days. But, more to the point, you don't want to put everything under prototype because a given method might not be useful or semantically meaningful as a part of every object in the language.

Comment: Thank you and answer accepted. However, I just have to say, the way things gets looked up proto chain wise, my newly created object will look at Object's prototype first and not Object, so I felt like I would have put everything under prototype.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read a little about OOP. Here's a good place to start on why "static" methods are useful, and why you don't want everything as part of your instance objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080150/when-should-i-use-static-methods-in-a-class-and-what-are-the-benefits

Comment: thank you and much appreciated and yes, I don't have formal training in OOP(in classic sense) so this is needed. I will peruse them. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In fact `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myObject, "a")` calls `myObject.GetOwnProperty("a")` but it's an internal method. [source](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.3)

We can only speculate why it was made this way, but I think it makes sense to define these utility functions as methods of `Object` object instead of making them inheritable via `Object.prototype`.

A more clear example would be `Object.keys` method. If it was `Object.prototype.keys` it would cause trouble every time we wanted to create `var inMyPocket = { keys : true }`. So now to reliably list `keys` of the object we would need to use `Object.prototype.keys.call( inMyPocket )`, because we couldn't be sure if `inMyPocket.keys()` refers to the prototype method or was re-defined.