# how can i call a method of a class within the main method without using object in java

Tags: java

Hi after a long time i am learning java , i have a confusion in calling the method without the help of the object.

public class VariablesInJava {

int instanceField=5;

static String staticField = "apple";

public void method() {

final String localVariable = "Initial Value";

```
    System.out.println(localVariable);
```

}

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    VariablesInJava obj = new VariablesInJava();

    System.out.println(obj.instanceField);
    System.out.println(obj.staticField);
    System.out.println(VariablesInJava.staticField);
    System.out.println(new VariablesInJava().instanceField);
    obj.method();

}
```

}

How can i call the method() without the help of object ?

Comment: Methods are part of objects. Methods can't exist without objects. That's like asking for a tutorial on driving a car without wheels. --- Although you should look at static methods.

Comment: You can define your methods to be static. But you should know when to use one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080150/when-should-i-use-static-methods-in-a-class-and-what-are-the-benefits

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method and call the method without creating an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Since main method is a static method you either need to create  an object of class **VariablesInJava** and then call it or make the "method" static.
Do this :

```
public static void method()
```

Now you can simply call method() without creating an object.

Hope that helps.