# NullReferenceException When calling class function c#

Tags: c#, class, nullreferenceexception

When I try to call this function I get NullreferenceException, if the code looks weird thats because I'm translating from c++ to c#.

```
public class MyPlayer_t
{
    int pLocal;
    public int Team;
    public int Health;
    public float[] Position = new float[3];

    public void ReadInformation()
    {
        pLocal = Mem.ReadInt(Client + playerBase);
        Team = Mem.ReadInt(pLocal + teamOffset);
        Health = Mem.ReadInt(pLocal + healthOffset);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Position[i] = Mem.ReadFloat(pLocal + Pos);
        }
    }
}

MyPlayer_t MyPlayer;

// This is how I call it
MyPlayer.ReadInformation();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make object/instance of class using `new` keyword:

```
 MyPlayer_t MyPlayer = new MyPlayer_t();
 MyPlayer.ReadInformation();
```

Here is [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) to learn about the classes in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Try and create an *instance*, and then call it.

```
var player = new MyPlayer_t();
player.ReadInformation();
```

If you wanted to actually call it as you've suggested, the class would need to be `static`, see the following [C# static vs instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765290/c-sharp-static-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonable. You have at first create an instance of the class. Like below:

```
MyPlayer_t myPlayer = new MyPlayer_t();
```

Then you can call it's method called `ReadInformation` like below:

```
myPlayer.ReadInformation();
```

The reason why you were getting this error was the fact that this line of code

```
MyPlayer_t MyPlayer;
```

creates a variable that can hold an object of type called `MyPlayer_t`. Since you *don't* assign to this variable a value, it gets it's default value, which is `null`. Then you try to call a method called `ReadInformation` on the the type that is stored in variable called `MyPlayer`. However, since `MyPlayer` is `null` you get this exception.