# How I can sort below Array in jquery or .NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery

How can I sort "YearMonth" text using Year & Month?

```
MyArray = ['2019APR', '2019AUG', '2019DEC', '2019FEB', '2019JAN',  
'2019JUL', '2019JUN', '2019MAR', '2019MAY', '2019NOV', '2019OCT',  
'2019SEP', '2020APR', '2020AUG', '2020DEC', '2020FEB', '2020JAN',  
'2020JUL', '2020JUN', '2020MAR', '2020MAY', '2020NOV', '2020OCT', '2020SEP']
```

**Output Require**

```
['2019JAN', '2019FEB', '2019MAR', '2019APR', '2019MAY', '2019JUN',  
'2019JUL', '2019AUG', '2019SEP', '2019OCT', '2019NOV', '2019DEC',  
'2020JAN', '2020FEB', '2020MAR', '2020APR', '2020MAY', '2020JUN',  
'2020JUL', '2020AUG', '2020SEP', '2020OCT', '2020NOV', '2020DEC']
```

I know `Sort()` will sort my array in alphabetical order but any optimal custom sort function for this?

I got Answer two Ans

JS I found myself using this way:- https://jsfiddle.net/51u9nb6c/2/

And for .NET c# I mark correct answer

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+sort+array

Comment: You will need a sort function that accepts a custom comparison function. This function should split the date string into its components. The year can be converted to a number and used as is. If the year of two compared dates are the same then the function should look at the month string. You can use a pre-defined map/dictionary to get the numeric values of two months and then compare them.

Comment: If you're using C# you could also parse the dates with `DateTime.ParseExact("2019MAR", "yyyyMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and sort them directly without a custom comparison function. I don't know if JS supports date parsing like that.

Comment: Please choose _either_ JavaScript or C# for an implementation.

Comment: Your JS solution looks nice but can be simplified a bit: `return a[1] - b[1] || months[a[0]] -  months[b[0]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c#, you can use the [Array's Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0#system-array-sort-1(-0()-system-comparison((-0)))) overload that takes an Array and a Comparison as arguments:

```
var arr = new[] { "2019APR", "2019AUG", "2019DEC", "2019FEB", 
                  "2019JAN", "2019JUL", "2019JUN", "2019MAR", 
                  "2019MAY", "2019NOV", "2019OCT", "2019SEP", 
                  "2020APR", "2020AUG", "2020DEC", "2020FEB", 
                  "2020JAN", "2020JUL", "2020JUN", "2020MAR", 
                  "2020MAY", "2020NOV", "2020OCT", "2020SEP" };

Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => ConvertToDateTime(a).CompareTo(ConvertToDateTime(b)));

private DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string yyyyMMM) 
    => DateTime.ParseExact(
           yyyyMMM, 
           "yyyyMMM", 
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note: You don't have to use the `ConvertToDateTime` method, it's just a helper to avoid writing the exact same `ParseExact` call twice.

See a live demo on [<kbd>SharpLab</kbd>](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) (without the helper method)

Comment: Would it make a difference (e.g. in high performance scenarios) if `ConvertToDateTime` was static? (which my VS is suggesting to do)

Comment: @Fildor I guess it could make a performance difference, but I seriously doubt that would make a true performance bottle neck.  
Actually, after writing this comment I went to check and found a [Dev.To post](https://dev.to/aloneguid/c-net-method-call-performance-facts-1koi) claiming static methods are 6 times faster than instance methods, so if it's correct it might make a more significant difference than I thought.

Comment: Static vs instance: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765290/c-sharp-static-vs-instance-methods) (and probably others) (though doesn't appear to be any performance tests)

Comment: Rather than consider if ConvertToDateTime should be static/not static, if performance is a question, then you would be better off not using *any* DateTime functions - they are notoriously slow.   This is a convenience answer rather than a performant one (not saying it will be slow, just any DateTime Parse function will be slower than a simple split + dictionary lookup) (ie handcode the parsing yourself for performance).

Comment: **Edit** which it appears is what your js solution does - you should add that as its own answer as jsfiddle links *may* get lost in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

```
            string[] MyArray = {"2019APR", "2019AUG", "2019DEC", "2019FEB", "2019JAN",
                "2019JUL", "2019JUN", "2019MAR", "2019MAY", "2019NOV", "2019OCT",
                "2019SEP", "2020APR", "2020AUG", "2020DEC", "2020FEB", "2020JAN",
                "2020JUL", "2020JUN", "2020MAR", "2020MAY", "2020NOV", "2020OCT", "2020SEP" };

            string[] sortedArray = MyArray.Select(x => new { s = x, date = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
                .OrderBy(x => x.date)
                .Select(x => x.s)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually sort the array, but instead returns a new array, sorted as the OP requests. Also, you're creating a new anonymous instance for each item in the array. 
All in all, this isn't a very memory efficient way to solve the problem, though to be fair it is a valid solution and unless the array is very long or this sort happens a lot of times, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : Is you method really any different?  In your solution is is not obvious what is being done under the hood.

Comment: In terms of memory usage, yes. I don't allocate any new reference types. In terms of runtime performance - I believe that if there is any difference, it's negligible.