# Assuming no class variables are involved, what are the advantages of using a private static method over a private method in Java

Tags: java, static, private-members

One advantage which I could think of was to **prevent accidental update to a class variable in future enhancements**. I would like to know if there are any other advantages.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169399/7804477) for C# mentions that there would be a minor performance improvement while using `static` method. Does Java compiler have a similar processing as well?

Comment: Use static _if the meaning is correct_. Don't try to get fancy with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the primary use cases for `private static` methods are reuse and readability of `public static` methods.

**Readability**
Suppose you have a large `public static` method with many branches, then it might be beneficial to readability to have each branch handled by a `private static` method. This is the approach advocated by books such as Clean Code.

**Reuse**
Suppose you have a number of `public static` methods with duplicated code, then it is usually a good idea to place the duplicated code in a `private static` method (unless of course the duplicated code is useful as a utility method in its own right).