# Why use a private static class?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages to Using Private Static Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135020/advantages-to-using-private-static-methods)

In a project that i'm currently working on I found a private static class definition. It was part of a baseclass that derived from Page. The class contains some public static methods which are used in some baseclass methods.

As the original developer of this piece of code is gone, I wonder what the benefit is. The methods only return enum values.

example:

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
   protected override OnInit(EventArgs e)
   {
     ...
   }

   private static class SomeClass
   {
      public static myenumtype GetCategory(int id)
      {
           switch(id)
           {
                case 1: return myenumtype.one;
                case 2: return myenumtype.two;
                default: return myenumtype.zero;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well without code it's hard to state exactly what benefits that style is granting you. It could have been something as simple as just encapsulating a lot of related properties into a type that is only needed by the containing class. Or he could have been bored and couldn't be bothered to think of a better way of doing something.

Comment: A static class can only derive from Object, so your statement 'I found a private static class definition. It was part of a baseclass that derived from Page' seems flaky.

Comment: @Adam: Good point, but if he was really bored why not created a private method. A class seems a bit bloated.

Comment: @ChrisBint: Interesting notion; perhaps the writer thinks this performs better. don't know if it does however...

Comment: @Justin: the class was part of the derived class; see the code I added

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a nested class, it might simply be to "namespace" the methods. Rather than have a load of static helper methods cluttering up Intellisense in the parent class, this way you can "group" methods with related functionality together.

Comment: Sounds fair, but it's the only one in the whole project (200K+ lines of code) and I don't know why he didn't choose a private method of the BasePage class instead.

Comment: If it's just the one method as in your code sample it doesn't make much sense. If it's multiple methods as in your first paragraph, then the point about namespacing still stands.

Answer (score 1):

This was probably done for encapsulation.

Having a private static class sounds like a helper class - it would make the code in the using class (the base class you are talking about) more concise and meaningful and take some incidental complexity into the private class.

Comment: Could be, but I think that would not be a sound solution to the cluttering problem. An extra helper class or a private static method instead of a private static class would be more logical and cleaner imo.

Answer (score 1):

Most a `private static class` with `public static` methods is a Extensions-Class which provides functionality you use in your code without making this functionality a member of your `Page`.

You don't want this functionality to be accessed from outer assemblies.

Read this for further information:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: Although this would be nice, extension methods actually have to be defined in a top-level static class rather than a nested class. (Assuming we're talking about a nested class here. Otherwise - good point! :) )